# How to find children classes of a certain class

Tags: php, class, children

How do I get a list of all classes that `extends` a certain class, in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If the classes has been defined you can use `instanceof` with `get_declared_classes`

You can try

```
$classes = array();
foreach ( get_declared_classes() as $class ) {
    if ($class instanceof CertainClass)
        $classes[] = $class;
}
var_dump($classes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after the child classes, then [is_subclass_of](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) might be of use whereas using instanceof would return the parent too.

```
$classes = array();
foreach ( get_declared_classes() as $class ) 
{
    if (is_subclass_of($class, "CertainClass"))
    {
        $classes[] = $class;
    }
}
var_dump($classes);
```